# Python Tkinter and MySQL Error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I'm getting an error : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`.

```
def submit():
    a=e1.get()
    b=e2.get()
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd="root",
      database="login"
    )
    sql="INSERT INTO log (name, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val= (a,b)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted")




form=Tk()
form.geometry("500x100")

name=Label(form,text="Enter Username").place(x=5,y=0)
e1=Entry(form).place(x=150,y=0)
password=Label(form,text="Enter Password").place(x=5,y=35)
e2=Entry(form).place(x=150,y=35)

submit=Button(form,text="Submit", command=submit).place(x=5,y=70)

form.mainloop()
```

Comment: specifying the line of the error might help getting a relevant answer (it is written in the error message)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the place function's output to the e1 and e2. Those function doesn't return anything and that's why your variable e1 and e2 are getting assinged as None.

You can change the e1 & e2 lines as below:

```
e1 = Entry(form)
e1.place(x=150,y=0)
```

And Same for e2.

Comment: Also wouldn't hurt to do the same with `name` and `submit` in case one ever needs to modify those items

Comment: Yes, this should be followed for all the widgets which are to be used further in the code.

Comment: same error ;(((((((

Comment: @AmanMadhukar Did you change both the lines? Also, can you modify the question as per the changes and add the new error traceback?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/My/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/login1.py", line 15, in submit
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
NameError: name 'mycursor' is not defined

Comment: This is a different error related to DB, the Tkinter problem which you have posted in question is fixed. For this error, you missing this line "mycursor = mydb.cursor()" Just add it in the submit function right after mydb variable assignment.

Answer (score -1):

### DONE

```
def submit():
    a=e1.get()
    b=e2.get()
    import mysql.connector
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="root",
      passwd="root",
      database="login"
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql="INSERT INTO log (name, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    val= (a,b)
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
    print(mycursor.rowcount, "record inserted")


    

form=Tk()
form.geometry("500x100")

name=Label(form,text="Enter Username")
name.place(x=5,y=0)
e1=Entry(form)
e1.place(x=150,y=0)
password=Label(form,text="Enter Password")
password.place(x=5,y=35)
e2=Entry(form)
e2.place(x=150,y=35)

submit=Button(form,text="Submit", command=submit).place(x=5,y=70)

form.mainloop()
```